# If I create a varying electric field and it will then create a varying magnetic field, so will it also create light? Will I see a light ray?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, magnetic-fields

If there is an electric field which is changing in time, lets say I create one, then it should create a varying magnetic field. So that means that there is an electromagnetic field, and oscillating electromagnetic field is light. So will I see light? A ray of light or something when I create a varying electric field?

Comment: light is a very small part of the electromagnetic spectrum, between NUV (near ultra violet) and NIR ( near infrared ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Light_spectrum.svg  inhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

Comment: So (developing Anna v's comment) you'll make an electromagnetic wave, but unless your fields are changing at the a frequency in the right band (between about  $4.3 \times 10^{14}\  \text {Hz and}\ \ 7.5 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$) the wave will not be visible – your eyes won't detect it.

Comment: I like your question! fyi I've just asked [Has anyone ever put an electrostatic dipole on a rotating shaft, spun it and demonstrated reception of a propagating wave in the far-field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709011/83380)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's correct in principle.

For visible light, the changes have to occur on time-scales of a femtosecond, $10^{-15}$ seconds, and on spatial scales of about a 100 nanometers, $10^{-7}$ meters, so you have to make the changes very quickly and in a very small space. Usually what you see comes from a whole bunch of little electrons wiggling around very fast.

Comment: It is not very difficult to generate radio waves with oscillating electric fields. Microwaves were a challenge.